# Format the SQL Server data from multiple date columns to single dated column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I had some data in db about payments by different customers. Few of payments from customers were honored (`PASS`) and few weren't (`FAIL`). The sample data in SQL Server 2008 R2 looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
|   Name    | Inst Date  | Status Date | Status | Amount |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| Jonathan  | 2014-12-03 | 2014-12-05  | PASS   |  25000 |
| Samantha  | 2014-12-08 | 2014-12-11  | FAIL   | 105000 |
| David     | 2014-12-11 | 2014-12-11  | PASS   |   2500 |
| Samantha  | 2014-12-11 | 2014-12-15  | PASS   |  50000 |
| Jonathan  | 2014-12-15 | 2014-12-05  | PROC   |   5000 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
                                                  187500
```

Management wants this data to be formatted like this.

```
+-----------+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|   Name    |    Date    |   ALL   |  PASS  |  FAIL  |
+-----------+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| Jonathan  | 2014-12-03 |   25000 |      0 |      0 |
| Jonathan  | 2014-12-05 |       0 |  25000 |      0 |
| Samantha  | 2014-12-08 |  105000 |      0 |      0 |
| Samantha  | 2014-12-11 |       0 |      0 | 105000 |
| Samantha  | 2014-12-11 |   50000 |      0 |      0 |
| David     | 2014-12-11 |    2500 |   2500 |      0 |
| Samantha  | 2014-12-15 |       0 |  50000 |      0 |
| Jonathan  | 2014-12-15 |    5000 |      0 |      0 |
+-----------+------------+---------+--------+--------+
                            187500    77500   105000
```

Using nested cursors one for `Name` and another for `Date` I built a temp table by fetching data from the source table under each loop and returned that from stored procedure. All is working fine, but it is disastrously slow when too much data (a year data for example) is presented.

Any suggestions on how can I optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with one union

```
select name, [inst date] as date, amount as all, 0 as pass, 0 as fail
from payments
union
select name, [Status date] as date, 0 as all, case when Status = 'PASS' then amount else 0 end as pass, case when Status = 'FAIL' then amount else 0 end as fail
from payments
```

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` after or David line won't work for example

Comment: Yes @MiguelRoxo, I added group by and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, why do you have multiple lines per customer? Why not something like:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Date, SUM(t.ALL) AS ALL, SUM(t.PASS) AS PASS, SUM(t.FAIL) AS FAIL
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        ,CASE WHEN Status IN ('PASS', 'FAIL') THEN [Inst Date] ELSE [Status Date] END AS Date
        -- OR SIMPLY one of the dates..
        ,Amount AS ALL
        ,CASE WHEN Status = 'PASS' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END AS PASS
        ,CASE WHEN Status = 'FAIL' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END AS FAIL
    FROM YourTable
) t
GROUP BY t.Name, t.Date
```

Comment: This too works but I need to add additional round of group by again to avoid separate dates appearing for each type.